# What is the difference between saint,yogi and sidhas?

Tags: worship, culture

I wish to know but the persons who dedicate their life in search of God or peace or getting to know the meaning of Life.People often call them as saints, Sidhas, Yogis and so.

My question:
What is the difference between these people Sidha,Siants,Yogi and so ? 
Who are all the right person to be worship ? 
If so, what are the ways to worship them ?

Comment: Siddhas are those beings who have control over their senses and have realized to certain extent that this World is a reflection of the Cosmic Mind. Saints are those who have had some realization or experience of the Self and have been Divinely Commanded to preach or to guide the Jivas. Yogis are those who have practiced some form of Yoga (Kriya Yoga, Jnana Yoga, Bhakti Yoga, etc.) and have a expert level of proficiency OR have attained Union with Divinity. Who are the right person to be worship? That is a individual thing, it depends on so many other factors sir! Good q, all the best sir!

Comment: Related [Meaning of Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2310/3500)