# what is the meaning of Sage?

Tags: puranas, terminology

In an [abridged version](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/brahmananda_purana/penance_of_agastya.html)
 of Brahmanda Purana,

> After a while, he saw Indra riding the elephant Iravata. The sage approached Indra, who did not appear to recognise and prostrate to the sage. However, the sage did not get angry and said, ―Indra! This is the garland given by the Divine Mother Herself.

In oxford dictionary "Sage" mean a very wise person. Is this right or It has different  meaning?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishi

Comment: Related or a duplicate of [Meaning of Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2310/5212)

Comment: it isn't related or duplicated. the question has two parts, and the question which may related isn't answer my question. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Then [edit] the question. Meaning of a sage, muni, rishi is already asked and answered in that question. Ask second part only. Also ask only **one**  topic per question.

Comment: Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni  which word mean sage? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Rishi is the word for sage. It is answered in the previous question. See all the answers.