# Why did Sri Krishna say he is Usanas among seers?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rishi

Sri Krishna says that he was Ushanas among seers in B.G.

> वृष्णीनां वासुदेवोऽस्मि पाण्डवानां धनंजयः।
>
> मुनीनामप्यहं व्यासः कवीनामुशना कविः।।10.37।।
>
> Of the Vrsnis (the members of the Vrsni clan), I am the son of
>   Vasudeva; of the sons of Pandu, Dhananjaya (Arjuna) [I am]; of the
>   sages too, I am Vyasa; **of the seers, the seer Usanas.**

Sri Krishna also says he is Bhrigu among Maharshis.

> **महर्षीणां** भृगुरहं गिरामस्म्येकमक्षरम्।
>
> यज्ञानां जपयज्ञोऽस्मि स्थावराणां हिमालयः।।10.25।।
>
> Of the great rishis, I am Bhrgu; of the words, I am the Single-syllable
>   (Om); of the sacrifices [performed with external objects], I am the sacrifice of muttering prayer; of the immovables, I am the Himalayan range.

---

**Edit 15-7-19**

I found the following mantra from Rig Veda, which mentions Usana.(IX.87.3)

> Rsi and Sage, the Champion of the people, cleft and sagacious, Usana in wisdom,  He hath discovered even their hidden nature, the Cows' concealed and most mysterious title.

**Edit 22-7-2019**

It was not Sri Krishna alone, who was greatest Yogi of his time, but even in Rig Veda, Indra stated that **he was Usana**.

> अहम मनुर अभवं सूर्यश चाहं कक्षीवां रषिर अस्मि विप्रः |
>
> अहं कुत्सम आर्जुनेयं नय ॠञ्जे ऽहं **कविर उशना** पश्यता मा ||
>
> I was aforetime Manu, I was Sūrya: I am the sage Kakṣīvān, holy
>   singer. Kutsa the son of Ārjuni I master. I am the **sapient Uśanā** behold me.

---

Now my question is what is the **greatness of Ushanas**?

Comment: what's ur exact point..to know if Usana is Shukra?

Comment: @YDS: Did I say in question ?   I am interested to know who the Usanas was and how great he was? By the way, I have in the Internet that Usanas was the mother of Sukracharya - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavyamata.  What do you think about this?

Comment: that's true..the name was derived from his mother's name...there is a story how he got name Sukra, i ll update that in answer..so once u know that he was Sukra, still u need to know his greatness? bdw mentioning all would be too long and site doesn't encourage list like answers..:)

Comment: @YDS: Let us see.  :-)  By the way, please link your answer to the mention made in Rig Veda also.  I have read in a Book that Usanas was mentioned many a time in Rig Veda.

Comment: "And, what is the difference between seer (कविः) and great rishi (महर्षि)?" - this should be a separate question and we already have [Meaning of Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2310).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of Sadhu, Sant, Rishi and Muni](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/meaning-of-sadhu-sant-rishi-and-muni)

Comment: Looks like there are two different questions here. As listed above, meaning and difference between Sadhu, Sant, Rishi, Muni is already asked and answered. Asking two different questions makes the question closed as too broad. Kavi is used as a proper noun in Rigveda mantra you quoted. Whereas the word Kavi means who writes. This is dictionary meaning and a common noun too.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: ok. I have deleted the 2nd question, which is not relevant here :-)

Answer (score 2):

**What does कविः mean and what is the greatness of Ushanas?**

As per, [Hindi Commentary By Swami Chinmayananda and Swami Ramsukhdas](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=37&hcchi=1&hcrskd=1) on **BG10.37**:

उशना (Usanas) is another name of **Shukracharya**. कविः is not just the author of a poetry but the one who is well-versed in scriptural principles; knower of the past, present and future.

Because Shukracharya is well-versed of the **Sanjivani vidhya**, author of **Shukraniti** and famous in **Vedas**, the God mentioned him as his Vibhuti.

---

**For what reason did Usanas obtain the name of Sukra?**

> Yudhishthira said, ... **for what reason did Usanas obtain the name of Sukra**?
>
> Bhishma said, ... Kuvera, represented the matter unto Siva of immeasurable energy, that first of gods, fierce and amiable, and possessed of various forms. And he said, 'Usanas, having spiritualised himself by Yoga entered my form and depriving myself of liberty, has taken away all my wealth. Having by Yoga entered my body he has again left it.' Hearing these words, Maheswara of supreme Yoga-powers became filled with rage.
>
> ... The lord of Uma, beholding Bhargava thus brought upon the palm of his hand, opened his mouth. The chief of the gods then threw Bhargava into his mouth and swallowed him at once. The puissant and high-souled Usanas of **Bhrigu's race**, entering the stomach of Maheswara, began to wander there.'
>
> ...The great ascetic Usanas, however, O chastiser of foes, from within Mahadeva's stomach, repeatedly addressed the god, saying, 'Show me thy kindness!' Unto him Mahadeva said, '**Go out through my urethra**.' He had stopped up all other outlets of his body. Confined on every side and unable to find out the outlet indicated, the ascetic began to wander hither and thither, burning all the while with Mahadeva's energy. At last he found the outlet and issued through it. **In consequence of this fact he came to be called by the name of Sukra**... ~[Mahabharata: Santi Parva: Mokshadharma Parva: Chapter 289](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b117.htm) [too keep it sort i have used ... to omit some text]

As mentioned above, he came to be known as Sukra (the word [शुक्र](https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=TT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=semen) is used for semen in Sanskrit/Hindi) because he came out from [urethra](https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=TT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=urethra) (from where semen comes out). This is more clearly explained in [Mahabharata in Sanskrit-Hindi by Pandit Ramnarayan Gita Press](https://archive.org/stream/Mahabharata04SanskritHindiPanditRamnarayanGitaPress/Mahabharata05_Sanskrit-hindi_panditRamnarayan_gitaPress#page/n848/mode/1up).

---

**What is the difference between कविः and महर्षि?**

The definition of कविः is elaborated above. For ऋषि or महर्षि, see the [rishi tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rishi) and already discussed posts [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/what-are-different-types-of-rishis) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6664/brahmarshi-maharishi-rajarshi-devarishi/22866#22866).

Comment: Many unanswered questions.  1) Do you have any other reference which says that Sukracharya is Usanas? 2) If the seer कविः indicates what you had stated, then what about Viswamitra?  In Ramayana, he was described to be authority in/creator of Mantras? 3) If Bramharshi is the highest level among seers, then Vasistha, Viswamitra, Atri, etc had also reached that level and authors of some Mandalas in Rig Veda.  What is the difference between them and Sukracharya?  4)  Rig Veda 2.23.1 is addressed to Brihaspati as कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम्.  Then how come Sri Krishna says Usanas as the same.?@YDS

Comment: @srimannarayanakv for ur 2-4) this is like asking why some particular avtaar is not in Dasavtaras...or God says he is Arjun among Pandavas but why not Yudhisthira...or among Vedas, Sama but why not Rig, Yaju...or among weapons Vajra but why not Sudarsana...bdw Brihsapati is mentioned in BG10.24..

Comment: That is why my question is what is the greatness of Ushanas?:-) @YDS

Comment: for 1) Swami Sivananda, Adidevananda, Shri Purohit, English translation of Shankaracharya's Sanskrit Commentary by Gambirananda mention Shukracharya for [this Shloka](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=37&ecsiva=1&etpurohit=1&setgb=1&etadi=1&choose=1)

Comment: When there is contraction between Rig veda's mentioning brihaspati as the greatest among seers and Sri Krishna mentioning about Usanas , naturally a question arises  :-)  @YDS

Comment: @srimannarayanakv greatness is there: mritsanjivani vidhya, shukraniti...etc... but when u start comparing it becomes subjective..if you would hv asked why x is mentioned but not y, your Q would hv been closed as primarily opinion based...

Comment: I have gone through your answer.   That was why I had asked whether  you have any other reference which says that Sukracharya is Usanas?

Comment: greatest always bring Q..in many cases, there is no common conclusion regarding greatest..for example, if u ask who is greatest god in Trinity..u might get different answers from different sects, philosophers, scriptures...

Comment: A question cannot be subjective, in my view, but answer can be.  Anyways, if you know the other sources about Usanas , please let me know.  @YDS

Comment: "the essential English translation for the same has been provided above" where is it provided? Adding English translation is essential directly rather than in a link.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma the link has hindi text only, essential transition is in first part of answer..

Comment: translated commentary by Swami Chinmayananda. It would be better if you translate that from Hindi to English as well. If it's not needed that can be removed totally. But I think that is also an important part since it explains significance of Ushanas and word Kavi. English is preferred to Hindi in Q&A you know it well.

Comment: If we read BG 10.37 , in which Usanas was mentioned by Sri Krishna,  Rig Veda 2.23.1, which is addressed to Brihaspati as कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम्. and Rig veda IX.87.3, in which Usanas was mentioned together,  I think we can infer that it was referring to  brihaspati @YDS

Comment: @srimannarayanakv no,  it was Sukra...Brahaspati comes together for comparison with Sukra at many places...when translators/commentators on BG mention Sukra then why do u think it was Brahaspati?? From Valmiki Ramayana to Puranas and Mahabharata all mention Usana as Bhragu's son...not sure why u got doubt on this...

Comment: Here's English commentary on that verse by Chinmayananda: "OF THE SEERS, I AM USHANA --- Nowhere do we find
any mention of this seer in the available popular books.
But Anandagiri somehow identifies Ushana with Shukra,
though he too does not explain how he identifies these
two together. The planet Venus, also called Shukra, was
the son of Bhrigu, and the preceptor of the Daityas. Shukra
is called Kavi in the Rig Veda."

Comment: "In the Upanishads, Kavi means a seer of the Vedic mantras.
Men of inspiration, declaring their experiences, without
ego-centric awareness, were called Kavis; later on the term
deteriorated to mean writers of poetry, who too, at the
sight of the spectacular Universe got themselves lifted
from themselves and seemed to enter into a realm of their
own brilliant notions, from the caves of which they sang
their harmonious rhythm of poetic cadence. Here,
however, it is used in the original meaning as a seer."

Comment: Can you provide links to your statement  -:" But Anandagiri somehow identifies Ushana with Shukra, though he too does not explain how he identifies these two together." ? @sv.

Comment: You can Google "holy geeta pdf" and check the commentary for verse 10.37.

Comment: @YDS: You stated that "From Valmiki Ramayana to Puranas and Mahabharata all mention Usana as Bhragu's son...".  Wherein Valmiki Ramayana it was stated that Usana was Bhrigu's son?

Comment: "Having said this, with eyes reddened with fire, Usanas, Bhrigu s son \to the inmates of his hermitage..." ~ http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-94 @srimannarayanakv

Comment: If it is from Uttara Kanda of Ramyana,  I can't accept this theory.   According to my understanding,  Uttara Kanda of Ramyana is an interpolated story. @YDS

Comment: @srimannarayanakv it's ur choice if u believe or not but Uttarkanda is in sync with Puranas... even Balakanda is considered interpolated but if u remove these 2 from VRM, it's not possible to connect all the dots...even few say rig veda  mandala 10 is interpolated...noone could prove or disprove with  % confidence...

Answer (score 1):

The greatness of Ushanas is due to Kavi. Hence Kavya Usanas, Usanas of Kavi, or from Kavi. Ushanas is the most famous of the Kavis. The original Kavis were a sub-line of Bhrgus.

Bhrgus home is in Bharuch, and also in that district is a town called Kavi, to remember the association of Kavis with Bhrgu.

Kavi became the most famous Kings of Iran, the Kayanian Dynasty.

Bhrgu, Kavi and Angiras are mentioned in Mahabharat as the most important names in history.

> "When the seed of Brahman was thus poured as a libation on that
> sacrificial fire, there sprang from it, O mighty one, three beings
> into existence. They were three male persons, endued with bodies that
> partook of the characters of the circumstances from which they
> respectively sprang. One arose first from the flames of the fire
> (called Bhrig) and hence he came to be called by the name of
> **Bhrigu**. A second came from the burning charcoals (called Angara) and hence he came to be called by the name of **Angiras**. The third
> sprang from a heap of extinguished charcoals and he came to be called
> by the name of **Kavi**.
>
> ........
>
> Endued with every prosperity, Angiras came to be called the offspring
> of Agni, and the celebrated Kavi came to be known as the child of
> Brahman himself. Bhrigu and Angiras who had sprung from the flame and
> the charcoals of Agni respectively, became the procreators of
> extensive races and tribes in the world. **Verily, these three, viz.,
> Bhrigu and Angiras and Kavi, regarded as Prajapati, are the
> progenitors of many races and tribes. All are the children of these
> three.**"

https://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Anushasna_Parva_Chapter_85:7 (8,9)

Kavi Usan, the Iranian Kavi Usanas, is also known in Arabic history, by Tabari associated with Soloman.

The Bhrgu, Kavi and Angiras names relate Indo-Aryan with wider Eurasian history, as those tribes are well-knwn in the West. Angiras can be identified with name Anglo.