# What is the source of the verse "Krishnam Vande JagadGurum"

Tags: krishna, identification-request

What is the source of this verse? Also what does it signify? Does this mean that Sri Krishna is first Jagadguru or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be from [Shree krishnaashtakam](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/prayers/krishna-ashtakam.asp) , 8 slokas eulogising  Sri Krishna.

> vasudeva sutam devam kamsa chaanuura mardhanam | devakee paramaanandam
>   **krishnam vande jagadgurum** ||

It means that **salutation to Sri Krishna, who is teacher for the world**

Sri Krishna was one of the greatest yogis of his times.

It doesn't mean that there were no such yogis before him.

Sri Krishna himself [mentioned](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35658/3869) about **Usana** in gita.